# AWS Step Functions: Transform a state array output to an object with keys

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I need to transform the output of a parallel step that comes out as an array into an object. Consider something like this:

Output of the parallel step:

`[1, 2, 3]`

I need to transform it to an object:

`{ "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3 }`

Any ideas?

Answer (score -3):

try this, hope this can help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var array = [1, 2, 3, 21];
    var output= {};

    for (var i in array) {
        output[inWords(array[i])] =  array[i];
    }
    console.log(output);
        

    function inWords (num) {
         var a = ['','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen'];
         var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];
        if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
        n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
        if (!n) return; var str = '';
        str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
        str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
        str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
        str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
        str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + a[n[5][1]])  : '';
        return str;
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```